# What's the problem with \setupdirections in context ? (texlive 2019)

Tags: context, arabic

I have this MWE which was working fine on texlive 2018 but with texlive 2019 produce a reversed non connected letters you need to remove  `\setupdirections` command to obtain a correct result.

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\mainlanguage[ar-dz] 
\setupdirections[bidi=global]
\setupalign[r2l] 

\definefontfamily [myfont][serif][Amiri]   [features=arabic]
\setupbodyfont [myfont]

\starttext
نص عربي 
\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have to set `method=one` in the directions setup:

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\mainlanguage[ar-dz]
\setupdirections[bidi=global,method=one]
\setupalign[r2l]

\definefontfamily [myfont][serif][Amiri]   [features=arabic]
\setupbodyfont [myfont]

\starttext
نص عربي
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what is the deference between `method=one` and  `method=two`?

Comment: The main difference is, that methods  `one` and `two` work and `default` doesn't ;) Honestly: I have no idea, maybe you can figure out what's going on here: https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkiv/typo-dir.mkiv