# Context overlapping headertexts with bidi=global

Tags: header-footer, context, right-to-left

In this example of RTL document  I have  added the line `\setupdirections[bidi=global]` and this produce overlapped text in the header  (the same example  would have given a correct result with TL 2022)

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\mainlanguage[arabic]
\setupdirections[bidi=global]
\setupalign[r2l] 

\setupbodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic]


\definefontfamily [myfont][serif][Amiri] [features=arabic]
\definefontfamily [myfont][mono] [Latin Modern Mono]
\setupbodyfont [myfont]


\setuppagenumbering[state=none]


%\setupheadertexts [left][يمين] % this give correct result (non overlapped texts)
\setupheadertexts [يسار][يمين]

\starttext

text

\stoptext
```

Comment: maybe related : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506403/264024 , also looking at https://wiki.contextgarden.net/RTL#Basics it seems that  all examples use `method=one`, not sure why, haven't looked at the source code, but your MWE gives the expected result (I think) with `method=one`. I changed the title, hope it is OK.

Comment: @UdiFogiel Thanks this solve the issue, manuals  of  context do  not provide explanations about bidi methods  and the differences between them